# Azure DevOps : I want to add a task in my pipeline that can copy some files from my Azure Repo into an On premise VM. Any leads?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a requirement to create an Azure DevOps pipeline that can copy files from my Azure Repo to a path on an On-premise VM (a SQL server to be precise). Could anyone advise on how to get started on this?

Comment: I tried to use the "Windows Machine File Copy task" but it requires that I provide a dedicated Admin username and password. The user account does have access to the destination path using Windows authentication but there doesn't seem a way to use that option within the task.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add a checkout task to the pipeline. You would define the repo as a source and then add a step to checkout the repo. Here's some [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops) concerning checking out multiple repos using yaml that should get you started

Comment: I have gone through the documentation and it seems like the check out is to copy files from the source Repo onto the Agent machine. My requirement is that I need to copy files from the source Repo onto a destination machine : a Windows Server.

Comment: You would need to have a self-hosted agent on the Server to checkout the files to it. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install). The alternative is to use a MS agent and have a task scuh as [Copy files over ssh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/copy-files-over-ssh?view=azure-devops). However, it's definitely easier to just have the self-hosted agent on your VM and use that in the pipeline to checkout your repo